# How to apply condition on one to many relationship in entity framwork

Tags: entity-framework

I have two objects with one to many relationship. I want to apply condition on second collections of object. Below is my code.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
IQueryable<DB.ProductionDB.CDCPortalApplicant> applicant = from app in productionEntities.CDCPortalApplicant.Include("CDCPortalUnit")
                                                                   where app.FirstName == firstName && app.LastName == lastName && app.EmailAddress == emailAddress && app.Created > date &&  app.CDCPortalUnit.PropertyId == propertyId
                                                                   select app;
```

Here CDCPortalUnit has more than one object for CDCPortalApplicant object

```
app.CDCPortalUnit.PropertyId == propertyId
```

actually I want to retrieve the CDCPortalApplicant object based properyID which is available in CDCPortalUnit object. CDCPortalApplicant object have multiple instance of CDCPortalUnit object.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you wish to achieve, what you've tried, and what is going wrong. I'm honestly not sure what you specifically want to achieve.

Comment: And please format your code properly.

Comment: Hi Flater,actually I want to retrieve the CDCPortalApplicant object based properyID which is available in CDCPortalUnit object. CDCPortalApplicant object have multiple instance of CDCPortalUnit object. Please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Gert Arnold ,  Flater did you get the chance to look into this